# Favicon with Rails 3.1 not showing up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I can't get my favicon to show up. It's called `favicon.ico` and inside of public directory (folder). My development log shows no problems with the favicon. I put the link in my application layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
        <%= favicon_link_tag "/favicon.ico" %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= yield %>
    </body>
</html>
```

But its still not showing up in Firefox. I cleared my cache with Firefox and I also tried `<%= favicon_link_tag %>` too. I haven't tried production but can you even see it in localhost? What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

So its showing up in Chrome but not Firefox. Any idea why?

Comment: Clear the cache again in Firefox (I usually just clear everything) and then check out the network traffic when you load your page. Make sure that favicon.ico is being requested.  If not, then it's probably been cached somewhere. I had lots of issues with this the other day but after a couple of cache clears it suddenly started working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clear the cache again in Firefox (I usually just clear everything) and then check out the network traffic when you load your page. Make sure that favicon.ico is being requested. If not, then it's probably being cached somewhere. I had lots of issues with this the other day but after a couple of cache clears it suddenly started working.

Answer (score 13):

If you suspect caching is the problem, you could also trick the browser into loading the new icon by adding a parameter to the filepath.

Instead of

`favicon_link_tag "/favicon.ico"`

Use

`favicon_link_tag "/favicon.ico?1"`